# How effective is using a LQFP type breakout board to test microprocessors?

Tags: microcontroller, breakout

There are many LQFP breakout boards available on the market today. An example can be found [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/LQFP-Adapter-/142037797422?hash=item21121cca2e:g:KhkAAOSwKtlWluow). I was curious as to their effectiveness in prototyping microcontrollers. I'm speaking of building circuits that will allow for basic programming of the chip, and nothing more. My main concern is that higher frequency clock signals may become distorted if ran through a breadboard. Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's really no good reason to even go that route with all the cheap dev boards available.

Comment: @mattyoung i want to learn how to design microcontroller circuits. Bypassing this step does not help.

Comment: And how do you think it helps? Microcontroller circuits are not hard to design. They generally require the micro and some caps, with requirements defined in the datasheet. That's a pretty pointless thing to prototype.

Comment: @mattyoung i mean,  not learning this is shooting myself in the foot. I have to learn the basics before moving onto advanced things.

Comment: My point remains, what do you really expect to learn from doing this?

Comment: @mattyoung i don't know.  That is exactly why i want to do it.

Comment: I don't think these provide a lot of learning potential.  The main purpose used to be a cheap way to get something to try out software or peripheral control an MCU when dev boards were expensive.  It isn't really a useful stepping stone between working with premade dev.  boards and building your own custom MCU board.  If you want to design your own, buy a dev board, examine it and the schematic, and then start drawing your own.

Comment: @Evan  I see. It's really that simple?

Comment: Pretty much.  Many microcontrollers have a built in oscillator, so all you _need_ is the MCU, power, a few capacitors, and the programming header.  The rest is just whatever you need for your application.  There is definitely stuff you will have to learn relative to using premade dev boards, but it is mostly software/configuration stuff like getting the clock registers programmed, or the pin muxing, or figuring out the IO addresses on a particular MCU.  The board layout is basically trivial, at least for a basic system.

Comment: The question is largely opinion-based.  But the eBay link is what may end up sealing its fate.  My suggestion is twofold.  (2) Rewrite the question.  Use something other than eBay link as a reference, (1) take this question to our [EE.SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).